# Need to specify which jre NativeJ uses at launch time (not compile time)

Tags: java

On our test machine we are running multiple versions of our app that each require separate jre versions (used to test new jre versions before rolling out changes to customers) - the problem is NativeJ specifies the custom jre at compile time, but we would like to specify this in the ini file. (so we do not have to re-compile the exe each time we change which jre we are running.) - is this possible?

tried adding the JvmDll option to the iniFile - but it appears (also based on NativeJ Online Help) that this option does not work in the ini.

Comment: I've got no experience with NativeJ, but the docs indicate you can set a "JVM DLL" parameter, and then it checks for the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable, which you could set at runtime (http://www.dobysoft.com/products/nativej/help/index.htm)

Comment: silly frames.. http://www.dobysoft.com/products/nativej/help/html/advanced/searchjvm.html

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of trying that. I had only tried setting the jvmdll parameter in the ini file without success. I'll test changing the JAVA_HOME variable.